# Jackson & Scala: How to get property value from a list of objects by property value?

Tags: java, scala, jackson

I'd like to get the `requestedInstanceCount` from `instanceGroupName` = `slave`. How can this be achieved with Jackson?

Below is the `job-flow.json`:

```
{
  "generalId": "ABC"
  "instanceCount": 4,
  "instanceGroups": [
    {
      "instanceGroupId": "CDE",
      "instanceGroupName": "master",
      "requestedInstanceCount": 1
    },
    {
      "instanceGroupId": "FGH",
      "instanceGroupName": "slave",
      "requestedInstanceCount": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

So far this is what I have:

```
  val jobFlowJson: String = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/mnt/var/lib/info/job-flow.json")))
  val jsonNode = mapper.readValue(jobFlowJson, classOf[JsonNode])
  val instanceCount = jsonNode.get("requestedInstanceCount").asInt
```

But there are 2 values and the order between master & slave can change at any time. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through the JSON tree step by step:

- get the `instanceGroups` as an array
- iterate over the array to find the item you want
- extract the value `requestedInstanceCount`

Something like this (pseudo Scala code):

```scala
jsonNode.get("instance groups")
  .asArray
  .collect {
    case item if item.get("instanceGroupName").asString == "..." =>
      item.get("requestedInstanceCount")
  }
```

---

Or define some case class representing the structure and pass on your JSON into the case class. It will be way easier to manipulate if you have no specific reason to not do this.